# How to redirect back to edit page from a called function?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes

On `edit.blade.page` there is a button for file deleting which leads to the `update` method in a controller. The `update` method calls private `deleteImage` method from which I want to redirect a user back to `edit.blade.page`, but it redirects me somewhere else.
I have tried all approach from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects)

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
        ($request['method']==true) ? $this->imageDelete($request, $id) : null;
    }

private function imageDelete (Request $request, $id){
        if($request['method']=='destroy'){
            $file = public_path().'/storage'.$request['old_image'];

            $validatedData = $request->validate(['images'=> 'string',]);

            $old_images = explode(',', $request['images']);
            $paths = array();
            foreach ($old_images as $old){
                ($old != $request['old_image']) ? $paths[] = $old : null ;
            }
            (File::exists($file)) ? File::delete($file) : null;

            Announcement::where('slug', $id)->update(array_merge($validatedData,array('images'=>implode(",",$paths),)));
            return redirect()->route('announcements.edit',[$id])->with('status',1);
        }
        return redirect()->route('announcements.edit',[$id])->with('status', 0);
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('announcements', 'AnnouncementController', ['names' => [
                                                                    'index' => 'announcements',
                                                                    'store' => 'announcements.store',
                                                                    'show'  => 'announcements.show',
                                                                    'destroy'=>'announcements.destroy',
                                                                    'update' => 'announcements.update',

                                                                ]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! It seems like laravel doesn't see the return from other functions rather than predefined by itself.
So the solution, in that case, would be making the return from within the update method

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
  return ($request['method']==true) ? $this->imageDelete($request, $id) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`route`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-route) helper with the [`redirect`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-redirect) helper to specify the route name you wish to go to:

```
return redirect()->route('your.route.name');
```

**Note:** This requires you to have named your route e.g.

```
Route::get('/test', 'SomeController@index')->name('test')
```

or you can pass the URL directly to `redirect`.

<sup>I've generally found that being explicit in what I want my code to do prevents mistakes / unintended side-effects down the line.</sup>

Comment: Although in the first place, I posted with `back()` method, I usually use this approach in my routing. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I added my route code maybe you can take a look once again?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 good options:

```
return redirect('/edit');

return view('your.view');
```

Either should be able to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually, you have one realistic option because, IIRC, just calling `view` won't fire the corresponding controller, it'll just show the view.